# Salto de línea en textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, mysqli

Tengo un formulario en php que guarda info en una base de datos mysqli, el problema surge cuando quiero leer la informacion de una etiqueta textarea (que permite guardar muchas líneas), al leer no me reconoce los saltos entre líneas y muestra todo el texto unido.

¿Existe alguna forma de arreglar esto? De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Adjunto el código que guarda y muestra los datos:

*Código para ingresar datos en la base:*

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Seleccione la imagen...<br> 
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
Nombre:<br> <input type="text" name="name" /><br><br>
Precio:<br> <input type="text" name="price" /><br><br>
Añadir promoción:<br> <input type="text" name="prom" /><br><br>
Descripción:<br> <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="5" style="width:70%; height:200px;"></textarea><br><br><br>"
</form>
```

*Código para mostrar datos en pantalla:*

```
var description = <?= json_encode($registro['descripcion'])?>;
```

Comment: Cuidado con las sugerencias que te están dando si el contenido del `textarea` va a ser recogido para almacenarlo en alguna parte. [Según este comentario del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php#49516) `nl2br` **no reemplaza los saltos de línea que ya tienes en tu contenido, sino que agrega otros**. Quizá sea mejor usar `str_replace`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda efectivamente me sirvió usar str_replace

Comment: No tienes que colocar dentro de el contenido de la pregunta lo de que si te pueden ayudar, se supone que esta es una comunidad, y si alguien sabe como resolver tus dudas lo harán.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por definición, [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) **inserta** saltos de línea HTML antes de todas las nuevas líneas de un string.

Si el contenido es tomado luego del `textarea` para presentarlo/almacenarlo en otra parte, puede que recojas un texto con más saltos de línea de los que realmente necesitas.

Una mejor alternativa podría ser usar **[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)**, del siguiente modo:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string);
```

---

#### Prueba

Podemos hacer una prueba entre `str_replace` y `nl2br` operando sobre dos cadenas con el mismo contenido:

#### `str_replace`

```
$string1="Lorem\nipsum\rdolor\r\n";
$str1 = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string1);
var_dump($str1);
```

Produce una cadena de 33 caracteres:

```
string(33) "Lorem<br />ipsum<br />dolor<br />"
```

#### `nl2br`

```
$string2="Lorem\nipsum\rdolor\r\n";
$str2=nl2br($string2);
var_dump($str2);
```

Produce una cadena de 37 caracteres:

```
string(37) "Lorem<br />
ipsum<br />dolor<br />
"
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función **nl2br** de php, que imprimirá el texto con sus saltos de línea.

En tu caso sería:

```
var description = <?= nl2br($registro['descripcion']) ?>;
```

[Aquí el enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) para más información.

Answer (score 1):

¿En dónde es que quieres "leer" la información? No sé, se me ocurre que podrías utilizar *nl2br* en php, de la siguiente manera:

```
var description = <?= nl2br($registro['descripcion']) ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el problema lo que hice fue implementar el siguiente código:

```
<?php $reemp = str_replace("\r\n", "</br>", $registro['descripcion']); ?>
var descri = <?= json_encode($reemp);?>;
```

Si no me equivoco el problema radicó en que al leer la info de la base de datos, los saltos no se interpretaban en lenguage HTML lo que causó el problema, gracias por su ayuda a todos los que comentaron.